# How can I extract R major.minor version from the unix command line?

Tags: r, bash, awk, version

on linux I need to be able to assign the R version to a variable, typically I am using R 3.4.1 as per `R.Version()`.

How can I get `3.4` in that case ie something like 
`export RVERSION=$(some-command)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following may help you.

```
R --version | head -1 | cut -d" "  -f3
```

***OR***

```
R --version | awk 'FNR==1{print $3}'
```

For me output is `3.5.0`

For putting into DOT profile use following.

```
R_VERSION=$(R --version | head -1 | cut -d" "  -f3); export R_VERSION
```

***OR***

```
R_VERSION=$(R --version | awk 'FNR==1{print $3}'); export R_VERSION
```

Then re-import your .profile by doing `./.profile` to make this variable available. Then check it by running command:

```
echo $R_VERSION
3.5.0
```

***NOTE:*** You could make variable by your own choice as I now I have created with `R_VERSION`.